# May a Muslim take another Muslim to non-Sharia courts for remonstration?

Tags: sharia

Is it legal under Sharia Law for a Muslim to take another Muslim to non-Sharia courts for remonstration?

Comment: Please ask one focused question per post.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any room for non-Shariah courts under Shariah law, as there is prohibition and severe condemnation of using any other man-made law:

> #### وأن احكم بينهم بما أنزل الله ولا تتبع أهواءهم
>
> And judge between them by what Allah has revealed and do not follow their inclinations
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:49](http://legacy.quran.com/5/49)</sup>

> #### ومن لم يحكم بما أنزل الله فأولئك هم الكافرون
>
> And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed - then it is those who are the disbelievers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:44](http://quran.com/5/44)</sup>

A non-muslim judge (for example one who is appointed over *Dhimmis* in some of their internal matters, according to some madhabs) does not have any jurisdiction over a Muslim:

> #### ولن يجعل الله للكافرين على المؤمنين سبيلا
>
> And never will Allah give the disbelievers over the believers a way [to overcome them].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:141](http://quran.com/4/141)</sup>